# Computer Randomly Turns Off Playing Taxing Gamesa

Tags: windows-10, ssd, graphics-card, cpu, power-supply

I've tried everything now. I've formatted my SSD and reinstalled windows. Monitored for overheating with no obvious problems. Nothing seems to be obvious as to why this is happening.

Like I said in the title, it's completely random, but always seems to happen playing taxing games on it (Pummel Party, Call of Duty, CSGO sometimes, Valorant. But works fine with games like League of Legends for hours on end). My GPU + CPU temps don't really exceed 80C even with the most taxing jobs. I've ran multiple memtests with no problems, and I've never been able to reproduce this just benchmarking.

I figured it had to be the PSU with how things were acting, or a component drawing too much power. I decided to try out an excess 650W PSU (I currently have a 750W running in my rig). However when I installed it and tried to power on, the computer gets power for about half a second but never clicks fully on.

My rig has an i7-8700K and a GTX 1080 Founders Edition, plus 1HDD + 1SSD. Wattage calculators put it at around 430W requirement. If the 650W isn't working for it either, is it possible a component is drawing too much power, and if so, is there a way to test for it?

Comment: Instead of looking at the total wattage of the PSU you should check how much power is available on each voltage rail of the PSU. For CPU and GPU only the 12V rail is relevant.

Comment: @Robert I was told by EVGA to check it through BIOS and everything looked fine, not sure if there's something else I'm missing with that though